# Exit python script with pygame

Tags: python, pygame

How do I exit my Python Script without it waiting for an input for a user to exit the game with pygame

I want it to close the script when I press any key on my keyboard without it stopping and waiting for an input

```
import time
from neopixel import *
import argparse
import pygame, sys

LED_COUNT      = 59      # Number of LED pixels.
LED_PIN        = 18      # GPIO pin connected to the pixels (18 uses PWM!).
#LED_PIN        = 10      # GPIO pin connected to the pixels (10 uses SPI /dev/spidev0.0).
LED_FREQ_HZ    = 800000  # LED signal frequency in hertz (usually 800khz)
LED_DMA        = 10      # DMA channel to use for generating signal (try 10)
LED_BRIGHTNESS = 255     # Set to 0 for darkest and 255 for brightest
LED_INVERT     = False   # True to invert the signal (when using NPN transistor level shift)
LED_CHANNEL    = 0       # set to '1' for GPIOs 13, 19, 41, 45 or 53

def wheel(pos):
    """Generate rainbow colors across 0-255 positions."""
    if pos < 85:
        return Color(pos * 3, 255 - pos * 3, 0)
    elif pos < 170:
        pos -= 85
        return Color(255 - pos * 3, 0, pos * 3)
    else:
        pos -= 170
        return Color(0, pos * 3, 255 - pos * 3)

def rainbowCycle(strip, wait_ms=20, iterations=5):
    """Draw rainbow that uniformly distributes itself across all pixels."""
    for j in range(256*iterations):
        for i in range(strip.numPixels()):
            strip.setPixelColor(i, wheel((int(i * 256 / strip.numPixels()) + j) & 255))
        strip.show()
        time.sleep(wait_ms/1000.0)
    checkKeys()


def checkKeys():
    if keyboard.q:
        sys.exit()

looping = True
if __name__ == '__main__':

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-c', '--clear', action='store_true', help='clear the display on exit')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(LED_COUNT, LED_PIN, LED_FREQ_HZ, LED_DMA, LED_INVERT, LED_BRIGHTNESS, LED_CHANNEL)
    strip.begin()

    print ('Press Ctrl-C to quit.')

    while looping:
        rainbowCycle(strip)
        checkKeys()
```

I don't know how to do this

Answer (score 0):

hmmmm try this:

```
import sys
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_q:
            sys.exit()
```

Comment: How should i implement that?

Comment: at this exemple, if u press 'q' it will close, look for the key u want and change this: pygame.K_q